# MVC; Array in View to array in Model when submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays

I my view I can add 'actions'. A action can be a email or sms. If i make a action i show a table in the view. So if I have 5 actions and I push on the submit button then i want the actions send to the Model.

My View:

```
<table id="action-detail-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered detail-table hide">
    <thead id="headActions"></thead>
    <tbody id="allActions"></tbody>
</table>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Actions.Type, new { id = "action-types-type", name = "action-types-type" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Actions.Contact, new { id = "action-types-contact", name = "action-types-contact" })
```

Javascript in the view:

```
$('#addAlertModal form').submit(function (e) {
        var actionType = new Array();
        var contact = new Array();

        $('#allActions tr').each(function () {
            actionType.push(JSON.stringify($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text()));
            contact.push(JSON.stringify($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text()));
        });

        $('#action-types-type').val(actionType);
        $('#action-types-contact').val(contact);
    });

function addAction() {
    if ($.trim($('#allActions').find('td').text()).length == 0) {
        $('#headActions').append("<tr><th>Actie</th><th>Naar</th></tr>");
    }

    if ($('#action-type').val() == "Email") {
        $('#allActions').append($('#allActions').innerHTML + "<tr><td> Email </td><td>" + $('#action-email').val() + "</td></tr>");
    }
    else if ($('#action-type').val() == "SMS") {
        $('#allActions').append($('#allActions').innerHTML + "<tr><td> SMS </td><td>" + $('#action-sms').val() + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

And my Model:

```
public class AlertAction
{
    public List<string> Type { get; set; }

    public List<string> Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Now i get only 1 long string ofcourse. How can i fix this? I want to fill the 2 lists in the view. But @Model.Actions.Type.Add() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I switched away from using stringify to using postify a while ago which I've personally found better to work with as it works with MVC's default model binding. ([Readme](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/))

Example usage:

```
var data = {Type: [], Contact: []};
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    data.Type.push("Type " + i.toString());
    data.Contact.push("Contact" + i.toString());
}
$.post('someurl', $.postify(data), function(response) {
    // process response
});
```

Comment: Sorry my English isn't that good. I want to know how i can fill de lists in the Model from the View. I don't know how to do that!

Comment: Currently, on form submit, you populate 2 hidden inputs with stringify-ed types and contacts which get posted back to the Controller as strings. Hence, server-side you would need to split that string back out. What I'm saying, is instead of submitting the form like that, you can build up the data to post back to the controller as per my basic example, then use $.post. The 2 lists should then automatically bind to the AlertAction model (assuming that is the argument to the action being posted to). Full examples in that Readme link